# What is the difference between quotes and candles?

Tags: market-data, historical-data

Actually I have a software development task to develop a little web app that could analyze some liquid stocks quotes considering OHLC values.

So I'm researching some OpenAPI where I have found a method to get candles, but no quotes.

As far as I've concerned candles are not actual quotes but an approximation of them. So considering high candles granularity (candles built on a rapid minute intervals, for instance) can I use candles to represent quotes?

Comment: A quote consists of a Bid Price and an Ask price, which express a market maker's willingness to trade at a point in time. A candle (O H L C) refers to prices at which trades have actually occurred during an interval of time. So the concept is rather different. You can't really approximate one with the other IMO. You could assume that when you sell you sell at the price L and when you buy the price at which you buy is H, but it seems a rather sloppy approximation of the actual bid-ask spread.

Comment: We could say this: If the bid and ask do not change during the interval and there is at least one buy and at least one sell in the interval *then* L will be equal to the Bid Price and H will be equal to the Ask Price. (But otherwise they will not be equal).